# SP2010 - User Profile Sync not updating site collection data

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, user-information-list

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm composed of two WFE servers and I have the User Profile Service running on both of them. I am not using MySites. I setup the synchronization between AD and the User Profile Service and it's working correctly, I can see all of my users and their properties in the 'Manage user profiles' page.

I changed the mapping of the 'Office' property to a different AD attribute, triggered a full synchronization and after a while, I can see the new property values in the 'Manage user profiles' page - however all of the site collections are still showing the old value in the 'Office' field in the /_layouts/userdisp.aspx page:

Manage user profiles view (new data):
[image: Manage user profiles view]

Site collection user details (old data):
[image: Site collection user details]

I made sure to trigger the "UserProfileService - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" timer job and waited a few hours just in case. The job execution took very little time, but the ULS log is clean and does not report any error from the User Profile service.
Is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

`stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0`

If there are any => few hours, run:

`stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0`

Then, run the Full Sync timer job again. Re-check your site collection (or re-run `stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0` to see that their time is current).

Comment: Hey, it worked! Not at the first attempt though - the listolddatabases command worked and showed me a bunch of databases with recent dates, but when I launched the deleteolddatabases it returned a generic error. 
I checked in the ULS logs and found an 'Access denied' error (which is strange since I am logged in as farm admin) but then I added my own account with Full Control to the User Profile Service application permissions and it deleted all of the databases. After that I ran the Full Sync timer job and this time it took a while and updated all of the users! Thank you so much!